# Join with parameters

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I expected Rails' `joins` method to accept an array with a string and variable arguments, as I'm used to with `where`:

```
my_var = 42
Topic.where(["id = ?", my_var])
```

However, that doesn't work for `joins`:

```
Topic.joins(["LEFT JOIN `wave` ON `wave`.`obj_id` = ?", my_var])
```

How can I achieve the same (a string where the question marks will be replaced with sanitized variables) for the `joins` operation?

Answer (score 1):

Left joins are not really well supported in rails. I appreciate your effort to sanitize inputs. I personally also go one step further and try to eliminate any explicit SQL statements from my code and let it be handled by the underlying framework.

If you have a relation 'wave' you could do an 'implicit' left join with includes:

```rb
Topic.includes(:wave).references(:wave).where(wave: {object_id: my_var})
```

Or you can try using Arel. [an example gist](https://gist.github.com/mildmojo/3724189)

```rb
topics = Topic.arel_table
wave = Wave.arel_table

left_join_var = topics.join(wave, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
                      .on(wave[:obj_id].eq(my_var))
                      .join_sources

Topic.joins(left_join_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Topic.joins(["LEFT JOIN `wave` ON `wave`.`obj_id` = ", "my_var"])

or

Topic.joins(["LEFT JOIN `wave` ON `wave`.`obj_id` = #{my_var}"])